# Twig default to text within block if block is empty?

Tags: templates, twig, slim, templating, slim-3

On my template I am using the following to define a og:meta image url, some pages will override this.

`<meta property="og:image" content="{% block ogMetaImage %}{% endblock %}" />`

Now, what I want to do is have a default image there if the block is not set on one of my child pages that extend my main template.

Something like the following should be on the main template

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{% block ogMetaImage%}https://example.com/image.jpg{% endblock %}" />
```

Is there a way to do this with Twig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just like u described in your question actually.

*main.twig*

```
{% block foo %}
    Foo
{% endblock %}
```

*bar.twig*

```
{% extends "main.twig" %}
{% block foo %}
     Bar
{% endblock %}
```

Output: `bar`

*foobar.twig*

```
{% extends "main.twig %}
```

Output: `foo`